# Efficient counting of related objects in Django

Tags: python, django

So, I need to provide an article and amount of likes (Article model is a ForeignKey field for Like model) for it as a context for render method in Django.
I do it as follows:

```
article = Article.objects.get(pk=some_id)
likes_amount = article.like_set.count()
```

So the question is if there is any way to do it more efficiency than two queries, maybe using prefetch_related or aggregation?

Comment: Can you add your model to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to count likes for all articles in one turn try this:

```
from django.db.models import Count
articles = Article.objects.annotate(num_likes=Count('like'))
```

Now you can get a single article like this:

```
articles[0].num_likes
```

Comment: do I need to do it in views.py or models.py?

Comment: do it in your views.py